# Converting SQL query to TypeORM query

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, typeorm

I have this simple SQL:

```
SELECT
c.name,
c.planned,
(
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0)
    FROM public.transaction AS t
    WHERE t."categoryId" = c.id
) AS actual,
c.type,
c.id,
c."userId"
FROM public.category AS c;
```

and I am trying to convert this into a TypeORM query:

```
  const allCategories = await categoryRepository
.createQueryBuilder()
.select([
  'category.id',
  'category.name',
  'category.planned',
  'category.type',
])
.addSelect((subQuery) => {
  return subQuery
    .select('COALESCE(SUM(transaction.amount))', 'category.actual')
    .from(Transaction, 'transaction')
    .where('transaction.categoryId = category.id');
}, 'category.actual')
.where('category.user = :userId', { userId: res.locals.user.id })
.from(Category, 'category')
.getMany();
```

The issue is that the `actual` field is not returned and I can't exactly figure what I am doing wrong.

This is the SQL output of the TypeORM query:

```
SELECT
  "category"."id" AS "category_id",
  "category"."name" AS "category_name",
  "category"."planned" AS "category_planned",
  "category"."type" AS "category_type",
  (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM("transaction"."amount"), 0) AS "category_actual"
    FROM "transaction"
    WHERE "transaction"."categoryId" = "category"."id"
  ) AS "category_actual"
FROM
  "category"
WHERE
  "category"."userId" = $1;
```

Comment: How does th e the raw SQL look like

Comment: Can you try removing `category.` prefix in select in subquery and in alias definition?

Comment: @nbk I added the raw sql to the post

Comment: @MilosStojanovic removed them and tried to no avail

Comment: The select looks ok to me have you run the query in the database

Comment: @nbk Yes, with accurate results.

Comment: I found the issue and posted it below, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
  const allCategories = await AppDataSource.createQueryBuilder()
    .select('category.id', 'id')
    .addSelect('category.name', 'name')
    .addSelect('category.planned', 'planned')
    .addSelect('category.type', 'type')
    .addSelect((subQuery) => {
      return subQuery
        .select('COALESCE(SUM(transaction.amount), 0)', 'actual')
        .from(Transaction, 'transaction')
        .where('transaction.categoryId = category.id');
    }, 'actual')
    .where('category.user = :userId', { userId: res.locals.user.id })
    .from(Category, 'category')
    .getRawMany();
```

Fixed it by:

1. Using `getRawMany()` method instead of `getMany()`. Read [here](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#getting-raw-results) why that is. Essentially, the latter is used when you require specific data.
2. Using `AppDataSource` instead of the specific repository. I found that when using specific repositories I get copies of the same data. This makes sense, as my query has to beyond a single entity.
3. I am using `addSelect` instead of bundling them into an array because this is the only way to add aliases to the fields, otherwise, with `getRawMany()` the data was returned as `category_id` for example.